# How can I tell if the selected index in a ListView is a file or directory?

Tags: java, android, file, ftp

I have an Activity with a ListView. am using Apache FTP Commons to connect and populate the ListView with files and directories. How can I determine if the selected item is a file or directory?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.ftp);

        editAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        editUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        remote = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.localList);
        itla.setListItems(directoryEntries);
        remote.setAdapter(itla);

        remote.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        connect = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
        connect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                address = editAddress.getText().toString();
                user = editUser.getText().toString();
                pass = editPassword.getText().toString();
                ftpConnect(address, user,pass, 21);
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password,
            int port) {
        try {
            mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
            // connecting to the host
            mFTPClient.connect(host, port);

            // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
                // login using username & password
                boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

                /*
                 * Set File Transfer Mode
                 * 
                 * To avoid corruption issue you must specified a correct
                 * transfer mode, such as ASCII_FILE_TYPE, BINARY_FILE_TYPE,
                 * EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE .etc. Here, I use BINARY_FILE_TYPE for
                 * transferring text, image, and compressed files.
                 */
                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                ftpPrintFilesList(ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory());
                return status;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host );
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean ftpDisconnect() {
        try {
            mFTPClient.logout();
            mFTPClient.disconnect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG,
            // "Error occurred while disconnecting from ftp server.");
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory() {
        try {
            String workingDir = mFTPClient.printWorkingDirectory();
            return workingDir;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not get current working directory.");
        }

        return null;
    }

    public boolean ftpChangeDirectory(String directory_path) {
        try {
            return mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(directory_path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not change directory to " +
            // directory_path);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void ftpPrintFilesList(String dir_path) {
        try {
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
            int length = ftpFiles.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                File name = new File(ftpFiles[i].getName());
                boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();
                boolean isDirectory = ftpFiles[i].isDirectory();
                if (isDirectory) {
                    Drawable currentIcon = getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.folder);
                    directoryEntries.add(new IconifiedText(name, currentIcon));

                    // Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
                } else if (isFile) {
                    Drawable currentIcon = getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.mimetxt);
                    directoryEntries.add(new IconifiedText(name, currentIcon));
                    // Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
                }
                Collections.sort(this.directoryEntries);
                itla.setListItems(directoryEntries);
                remote.setAdapter(itla);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        String selectedFile = directoryEntries.get(position).getText();
        try {
            ftpPrintFilesList(selectedFile);
            itla.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
        Toast.makeText(FTPConnector.this, selectedFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }
}
```

The Toast returns the correct file name.

Here is the complete code using Backslash's suggestion for anyone who might find it useful.

```
public class FTPConnector extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    public ListView remote;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public FTPClient mFTPClient = null;
    public ToggleButton connect;
    public EditText editAddress;
    private String address;
    public String currentDirectory = "/";
    public EditText editUser;
    private String user;

    public EditText editPassword;
    private String pass;
    public File[] fileList;
    public HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    private List<IconifiedText> directoryEntries = new ArrayList<IconifiedText>();
    private IconifiedTextListAdapter itla = new IconifiedTextListAdapter(this);
    public String[] files;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.ftp);

        editAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        editUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        remote = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.remoteList);
        itla.setListItems(directoryEntries);
        remote.setAdapter(itla);

        remote.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        connect = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
        connect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    address = editAddress.getText().toString();
                    user = editUser.getText().toString();
                    pass = editPassword.getText().toString();
                    ftpConnect(address, user,
                            pass, 21);
                } else {
                    ftpDisconnect();
                    directoryEntries.clear();
                    itla.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password,
            int port) {
        try {
            mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
            // connecting to the host
            mFTPClient.connect(host, port);

            // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
                // login using username & password
                boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

                /*
                 * Set File Transfer Mode
                 * 
                 * To avoid corruption issue you must specified a correct
                 * transfer mode, such as ASCII_FILE_TYPE, BINARY_FILE_TYPE,
                 * EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE .etc. Here, I use BINARY_FILE_TYPE for
                 * transferring text, image, and compressed files.
                 */
                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                ftpPrintFilesList(ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory());
                return status;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host );
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean ftpDisconnect() {
        try {
            mFTPClient.logout();
            mFTPClient.disconnect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG,
            // "Error occurred while disconnecting from ftp server.");
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory() {
        try {
            String workingDir = mFTPClient.printWorkingDirectory();
            return workingDir;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not get current working directory.");
        }

        return null;
    }

    public boolean ftpChangeDirectory(String directory_path) {
        try {
            return mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(directory_path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not change directory to " +
            // directory_path);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void ftpPrintFilesList(String dir_path) {
        map.clear();
        try {
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
            int length = ftpFiles.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                File name = new File(ftpFiles[i].getName());
                boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();
                boolean isDirectory = ftpFiles[i].isDirectory();
                if (isDirectory) {
                    Drawable currentIcon = getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.folder);
                    directoryEntries.add(new IconifiedText(name, currentIcon));
                    map.put(ftpFiles[i].getName(),
                            Boolean.valueOf(ftpFiles[i].isDirectory()));
                    // Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
                } else if (isFile) {
                    Drawable currentIcon = getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.mimetxt);
                    directoryEntries.add(new IconifiedText(name, currentIcon));
                    map.put(ftpFiles[i].getName(),
                            Boolean.valueOf(ftpFiles[i].isFile()));
                    // Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
                }
                Collections.sort(this.directoryEntries);
                itla.setListItems(directoryEntries);
                remote.setAdapter(itla);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        String selectedFile = directoryEntries.get(position).getText();
        boolean isDirectory = map.get(selectedFile).booleanValue();
        if (isDirectory) {
            directoryEntries.clear();
            itla.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ftpPrintFilesList(selectedFile);
        } else if (!isDirectory) {
            Toast.makeText(FTPConnector.this, selectedFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `FTPClient` by Apache Commons Net, if you list a directory the client will send you back an array of `FTPFile`s. Each `FTPFile` has a `isDirectory()` and `isFile()` method that can tell you if it is a directory or a file.

[Apache Commons FTPFile JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html)

So you basically need to find which file has the selected name in your list (maybe serching in it using the `getName()` function?) and then use one of the two methods provided in the `FTPFile` class

**UPDATE**

Try this:

Declare a HashMap instance variable

```
//this will contain the file name and it's isDirectory() result
HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

Now, at the beginning of the `ftpPrintFilesList(path)` method:

```
//resets the map, you are listing new FTPFiles, so older ones need to be removed
map.clear();
```

Then, in your `for` loop, in `ftpPrintFilesList(path)` add every FTPFile info to the map like this:

```
//Add file's name and isDirectory() value to the map
map.put(ftpFiles[i].getName(),new Boolean(ftpFiles[i].isDirectory()));
```

Finally, in the `onItemClick` method, just use

```
boolean isDirectory = map.get(selectedFile).booleanValue();
```

It will return `true` if the selected item is a directory, `false` if it is a file

Comment: Ok I understand this but I'm unclear on where to do the 'is' checks. Could you please provide a short code sample referencing my code?

Comment: @RapsFan1981 What is `itla` in your code? can you post the full code?